# Automorphism of direct product of rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, automorphism-group, direct-product

> Let $$R=A_1\times A_2\times\dots\times A_n.$$ Let's assume there are no non trivial automorphisms of these $A_i$s. I claim that the only possible automorphisms of this structure are the permutations of the $A_i$s. So, there are a total of $n!$ automorphism possible over this structure.

Question is how to prove this. I am proceeding in this way: let $R\cong A\times (0)$, $(0)$ being the zero ring. Now, $(a,0)$, $a\in A$, can only get mapped to $(a,0)$ or $(0,a)$. This can be established via some simple isomorphism argument. But I am not been able to generalize this to any ring product. Any help are welcome.

Comment: Are $A_i$ assumed to be the same (or, isomorphic to each other)? Otherwise permutations won't work.

Comment: This is false. Just take $n=2$ and consider $(A \times B) \times (A \times B)$ where $A$ and $B$ are not ismorphic.

Comment: Why $A_i$s have to be isomorphic for this? For $i=2$, if we just swap each tuple, then all the conditions for isomorphism are valid...

Comment: An automorphism goes from a ring $R$ to itself. Swapping tuples gives isomorphic rings, but not the same rings.

Comment: Isn't there any other way so that the product is isomorphic but the individual rings are not? If the rings are isomorphic then their product will be as we can just use the isomorphism between these rings, but why the converse is true?

Comment: @RghtHndSd did you mean $A_i$s do not have to be isomorphic by your example? I did not quite get what you said?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You meant that there are at most $n!$ possible automorphisms all given by permuting the isomorphic $A_j$.

RghtHndSd showed a counter-example, eg. $A_1=A_2=\Bbb{F}_p\times \Bbb{Q}$ then $((a,b),(c,d))\to ((a,d),(c,b))$ is an automorphism of $A_1\times A_2$.

If the $A_j$ are integral domains then your claim is true, because the $e_j = (1,\ldots,\underbrace{0}_{j \ th},1,\ldots)$ are the only elements such that $e_j R$ is a prime ideal and $e_j^2=e_j$. An automorphism  $\sigma\in Aut(R)$ must permute them. So it permutes the $1-e_j$, thus it induces an isomorphism $$A_j\cong (1-e_j) R \quad to\quad A_{\sigma_j} \cong (1-e_{\sigma_j}) R$$ And two distinct isomorphisms $A_j\to A_{\sigma_j}$ give a non-trivial automorphism of $A_j$, that you assume to not exist. Thus $\sigma$ is determined by the $\sigma_j$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116537/discussion-on-answer-by-reuns-automorphism-of-direct-product-of-rings).